# How to get this div into the right position

Tags: html, css

I am working on a win8-applike webdesign, and find it quite hard to position the divs properly.

First of all my code an a jsfiddle of how it looks like at the moment:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="appWrapper">
    <div id="app_logo">

    </div>
    <div id="app_text">

    </div>
    <div id="app_login">

    </div>
    <div id="app_kategories">

    </div>
    <div id="app_register">

    </div>
    <div id="app_buy">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#app_logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    background-color: #FFD300;
}

div#app_text {
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 31em;
    width: 30em;
    background-color: #7109AA;
}

div#app_login {
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    height: 15em;
    width: 35em;
    background-color: #7109AA;
}

div#app_kategories {
    float: bottom;
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    background-color: #7109AA;
}

div#app_register {
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 35em;
    background-color: #7109AA;
}

div#app_buy {
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 82em;
    background-color: #FFD300;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gGWfr/embedded/result/

so the purple div in the left upper corner which you dont really see is `app_kategories` I want to position it under the `app_logo`, which is the yellow div on the top left.
I don`t know how to get it there.

What I am asking is for ideas how to make this possible, and I am also wondering if there are better ways of realizing some kind of Win8like designs, because in my version with smaller screens it could look quite badly, I am also thinking about making the scales % and not em.

I found this website http://etchapps.com/ which looks pretty cool, but its not in the source code how they did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float:bottom` is not a valid CSS definition. You can set [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) to "left","right","none", or "inhertit".

I had success by wrapping `div#app_login` and `div#app_kategories` in a containing `div` and floating that `div` left.

I also removed the `floats` from the two child `divs`.

### HTML:

```
<div id="appWrapper">
    <div id="container_left">
        <div id="app_logo"></div>
        <div id="app_kategories"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="app_text"></div>
    <div id="app_login"></div>
    <div id="app_register"></div>
    <div id="app_buy"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
div#container_left {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

div#container_left div#app_logo {
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    background-color: #FFD300;
}

div#container_left div#app_kategories {
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    background-color: #7109AA;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gGWfr/1/

## EDIT:

Due to ["margin collapse"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), the `app_login` and `app_kategories` divs appear to have different sized margins than the rest of the boxes.

To fix this, I floated and immediately cleared floats on those two boxes.

I'm sure there are better (less messy/hacky) methods of avoiding margin collapse. However, this is one method that seems to work because margins will not collapse on floated elements.

```
div#container_left div#app_logo {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    background-color: #FFD300;
}

div#container_left div#app_kategories {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    background-color: #7109AA;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gGWfr/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea why space between those two is smaller than how it is with the other elements? The margin should be the same actually

Comment: I didn't notice that. That's caused by ["margin collapse"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you need to look at. First one is that you have not cleared any of your floated elements which is necessary to avoid layout issues. I suggest reading up on Chris Coyier's post to get more familiar with floats.

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

There are many ways to clear floats such as the clearfix hack or to just apply `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element.

Secondly if you want to have a responsive layout you need to be using percentage based widths along with media queries. Try looking into a grid system to get started. Again Coyier has great post on it here:
 http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/ . 
There are literally dozens to choose from such as twitter bootstrap, foundation by zurb, gumby, 960 grid, etc.

Here is a simple one:

http://simplegrid.info/

Hopefully that will get you started. Once your layout is right you can use css positioning to move things around.

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Chris is not paying me I swear, just a great blog.